# Does tensorflow object detection support distribute strategy?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

#### System information

- **What is the top-level directory of the model you are using**:object detection
- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**:No
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**:Centos 7.5
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**:source
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**:1.9.0
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**:0.19
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**:9.0
- **GPU model and memory**:Titan 1080 Ti / 8G
- **Exact command to reproduce**:No
- **Distribute environment**:2 machines with 8 GPUs each

#### Describe the problem

I want to run a distributed training on object detection.
At first, I run the file 'model_main.py' by simply setting the 'TF_CONFIG' in the command and it runs smoothly.  Is this a correct way to run a distributed training?
But this way seems to be an asynchronous training.
And in order to run a synchronous training,  I config the 'RunConfig' as blow, as it mentioned at [Distribution Strategy](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/distribute):

```
config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(train_distribute=tf.contrib.distribute.CollectiveAllReduceStrategy())
```

it reported:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CollectiveAllReduceStrategy'.

Does tensorflow object detection support distribute strategy?
If yes, what is the difference between using distribute strategy or not?
If no, is there an other way to run a synchronous training?

Answer (score 2):

you should update your tensorflow version >= 1.11